# Как задать ip на php?

Tags: ip, php

С помощью которого можно будет открыть сайт http://test1.ru/ под IP 239.89.08.46 и т.п.

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, на вашем компьютере в файле `hosts` надо прописать что-то типа

```
239.89.08.46    test1.ru
```

Тогда при запросе `http://test1.ru` ваш компьютер станет ломиться на ip 239.89.08.46.

На Маке этот файл лежит в `/etc/hosts`, в винде `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, кажется. Текстовый файл без расширения.

Обычно при разработке сайтов я создаю локальные версии их же, с доменом с припиской `.local` в конце. И тогда есть публичный рабочий [site.ru](http://site.ru), и есть мой локальный [site.ru.local](http://site.ru.local) — последний прописывается в `hosts` как

```
127.0.0.1   site.ru.local
```

**Upd.** Если я ещё более правильно понял вопрос, это требуется сделать исключительно в рамках скрипта php, без редактирования `hosts`.

В таком случае, если вы пользуетесь `CURL`, то надо открывать сайт по его ip, а в заголовки запроса дописать `Host: site.ru`:

```
$headers = array("Host: site1.ru");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Тогда cURL законнектится к нужному ip и скажет, что пришёл за контентом [site1.ru](http://site1.ru)

Comment: нет, я хотел что6ы пользователь вы6рал нужный ему IP, с которого нужно открыт сайт test.ru

Comment: а можно 6ез curl?

Comment: Подделывать IP задача совсем непростая. Желаемый IP - один из нескольких, назначенных вашему серверу? Тогда ещё можно повыбирать. Если же вы хотите накручивать счетчик голосования за красотку, и не спалиться, то [Тор](www.torproject.org) вам в помощь.

Comment: спс, все получилось, не я не хотел накручивать счетчик голосования, нужно 6ыло провести SQL инъекцию на свой сайт =)